# Set default text editor in KDE

Tags: kde, file-association

I want to change the default text editor in KDE (FWIW: from Kate  to code-oss). I know I can go to Settings->File Associations and change it tenths of times :( Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Replace the old answer by a better, cleaner, easier suggestion by kralyk. Copy from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368931/change-default-text-editor-in-fedora-20-kde#comment55074051_22389163)

There actually is a central location - kind of. When you change preferences for text/plain, you'll find out it's reflected in a whole bunch of other file types as well, because they somehow derive from text/plain. But it's not immediately visible.

*Following, the old answer*

The file that contains the "default text editor" setting is `/etc/xdg/kde-mimeapps.list`. So use nano (or your preffered editor) as super user

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/kde-mimeapps.list
```

and then change the text/plain settings. I changed min to `code-oss.desktop` which is the Code OSS editor.

Comment: This trick also works in the file associations settings mime types by setting text/plain as well via the settings GUI.